# using nodejs, express and basic auth how do i get username and password

Tags: node.js, express

I am using nodejs, express
A third party that will be calling my api will be using basic auth in the format of http://{username}:{password}@yourdomain.com/

I have tried

```
var auth = require('basic-auth')

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
     var credentials = auth(req)
     if (req.headers.authorization) {
       console.log("found headers");
     }
}
```

But this only works if the basic auth is passed in the header.

I can not seem to get the username and password from the URL(which is the only way this external party can call my api)

I then tried as suggested use url

here is what i am seeing now when i do a POST to

```
http://myusername:mypassword@localhost:4050/api/callback


var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');

var app = express();

app.use(function(req, res, next) {

    console.log("req.protocol=",req.protocol);
    console.log("req.get('host')=",req.get('host'));
    console.log("req.originalUrl=",req.originalUrl);
}

http.createServer(app).listen(config.port, function () {
     console.log("HTTP BandWidth listening on port " + config.port);

});
```

My console looks like

req.protocol= http

req.get('host')= localhost:4050

req.originalUrl=/api/callback

if i dump the entire req obj i do not see myusername or mypassword

i must be missing something obvious

Thanks
Randy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the built-in `url` package in Node.

https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/url.html#url_urlobject_auth

```js
const url = require('url');

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    const urlObj = url.parse(req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl);
    console.log('Auth info: ' + urlObj.auth);
}
```

Hope this helps!

---

**EDIT**: Well, I take that back. It looks like the use of username and password in the URI has been deprecated, and browsers may just be ignoring that information. [See RFC 3986](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt):

> **3.2.1.  User Information**
>
> The userinfo subcomponent may consist of a user name and,
>   optionally,    scheme-specific information about how to gain
>   authorization to access    the resource.  The user information, if
>   present, is followed by a    commercial at-sign ("@") that delimits it
>   from the host.
>
> ```
>   userinfo    = *( unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / ":" )
> ```
>
> ***Use of the format "user:password" in the userinfo field is***
>   ***deprecated***.  Applications should not render as clear text any data
>   after the first colon (":") character found within a userinfo
>   subcomponent unless the data after the colon is the empty string
>   (indicating no password).  ***Applications may choose to ignore or***
>   ***reject such data when it is received as part of a reference*** and
>   should reject the storage of such data in unencrypted form.  The
>   passing of authentication information in clear text has proven to be
>   a security risk in almost every case where it has been used.

And...

> **7.5.  Sensitive Information**
>
> URI producers should not provide a URI that contains a username or 
>   password that is intended to be secret.  URIs are frequently
>   displayed by browsers, stored in clear text bookmarks, and logged by
>   user agent history and intermediary applications (proxies).  ***A***
>   ***password appearing within the userinfo component is deprecated and***
>   ***should be considered an error (or simply ignored)*** except in those
>   rare cases where the 'password' parameter is intended to be public.

I added the bold and italics...

---

I tried this using the developer tools in Chrome and got the following:

**General**

```
Request URL:http://foobar:password@localhost:8888/test
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8888
```

**Response Headers**

```
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:19
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Thu, 08 Dec 2016 03:52:35 GMT
ETag:W/"13-uNGID+rxNJ6jDZKj/wrpcA"
```

**Request Headers**

```
GET /test HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8888
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.98 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

So, it doesn't even look like the username and password info is being passed along by Chrome. Unfortunately, I think you're out of luck if you're trying to use this schema. You may have to set the authorization headers, set your own custom headers (which is what I have done in the past), or pass your credentials in the query string.

Comment: Jeff thanks for the help, no luck updated the description of the error